# Ruby Selenium web driver running on Windows 10 - unable to locate element

Tags: ruby, windows, selenium, selenium-webdriver, windows-10

Here is my current setup:
**Windows 10**
Ruby installed using "windows installer". Ruby version 2.4

I have the ruby gem selenium-webdriver version 2.52.0 ( I have the older version as it was having issues with Firefox working correctly.

**What I am trying to do**
I navigate to "webpagetest.org" I am simply filling out a url and clicking the "start test" button. I **can** click on the button, but then my script just crashes. The script works, meaning the button is clicked on the UI and then switches to the next URL, but Selenium gives me the error message, and I am unable to interact because the script errors out.

**NOTE:** I can run my code without any issues from my 2012 Mac running Yosemite.  This issue only happens when running on my Windows 10. I need to run Ruby selenium webdriver from my Windows machine.

Here is a screenshot of what I am doing, and what that the name of the button is correct:

[image: Button class name is correct]

**Here is the error message I am getting**

```
FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_': Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"start_test"} (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError)
```

Here is a screen shot of the entire error message from my command prompt on my Windows machine:

[image: Error message from Command prompt]

**I have tried the following:**
Adding a wait to see if the page was just clicking too early.
Changed the way I was targeting the button
Tried "submitting" versus clicking on the button

Here is my current code:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'yaml'
require 'gmail'

test_site = 'https://www.webpagetest.org'
test_url = 'https://google.com'

# open a firefox browser and navigate to page testing site
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to test_site

# enter a URL and press the start test button
driver.find_element(:id, 'url').send_keys test_url
driver.find_element(:class, 'start_test').click

# store the URL of results page
results_url = driver.current_url
puts results_url

puts "made it here!"

# wait for the results page to load and the load time to show
begin
  element = driver.find_element(:id, 'LoadTime')
rescue
  retry if element.nil?
end
```

I would appreciate any help with this!  I think the problem is something Windows related ( I am fairly new to Windows ). Thanks for taking the time to read my question!

Comment: Can you clarify: the text is entered, the button *is* clicked, but then the error indicating the _textarea_ element is not visible? This suggests line 212 of your script looks for the textarea after it is no longer visible. Regardless, you'll need to post your code to get an informed answer from anyone.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention Sam, I have added the code and more information about what I am trying to do with the script.  Thanks so much for your feedback!

Comment: before sending keys, you must `clear` the url input box. (I'm guessing this is a miss from boiling your code down to an example.)

Comment: I don't have a Windows environment to help you test, but let me recommend: update selenium-webdriver -- you're way behind current. Also, you'll probably want to update Firefox and download geckodriver. And also I recommend watir as a nicer way to do webdriving with Ruby. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Sam, I will try those and report back on this Question :-)

Comment: Thanks so much Sam!  I upgraded Firefox and Selenium webdriver, and added geckodriver to the Path and the problem went away! Thanks so much :-)